# convert pandas float series to int

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am discretizing my series for a learner.  I really need the series to be in float, and I **really** need to avoid for loops.

How do I convert this series from float to int?

Here is my function that is currently failing:

```
def discretize_series(s,count,normalized=True):
    def discretize(value,bucket_size):
        return value % bucket_size
    if normalized:
        maximum = 1.0
    else:
        minimum = np.min(s)
        s = s[:] - minimum
        maximum = np.max(s)
    bucket_size = maximum / float(count)
```

Here is the line that causes the function to fail:

```
    s = int((s[:] - s[:] % bucket_size)/bucket_size)
```

The int() induces a casting error: I am unable to cast the pandas series as an int series.

```
    return s
```

If I remove the int(), the function works, so I may just see if I can get it to work anyway.

Comment: In the first branch, minimum is greater than zero, so subtracting it from all values sets the minimum to zero. 

In the second branch, minimum is less than zero, so adding the abs(min) shifts the data up to zero...

Comment: And unless `pandas` does something fishy, you might not be needing those `[:]` there.

Comment: What does "is currently failing" mean? Does it only fail in case `normalized==True`? You might have to set `s=s/np.max(s)` in that case. And you can still have trouble if `np.max(s)<0`. Is that possible?

Comment: No, it fails because of the int() function in line 11.  It cannot change the series from float to int.

Comment: So, are you sure it works right for the `normalized==True` case, if your input series has a maximum of, say, 10? For instance, for a `count` of 2, you'd have a `bucket_size` of `0.5`. But then for the maximal value of `s` you'd have `(10 - 10%0.5)/0.5==20`, much more than 2. I would expect that you have to do the same shifting to 0, but you also have to divide by the maximum.

Comment: Oh...normalized means that the max is 1.0 and the min is 0.0.

Comment: Well, I get that, but your function doesn't check that at all. If you believe that input parameter without checking, then OK, I thought this was a feature to normalize the data. Which would indeed not make much sense, in retrospect, as the resulting discretized signal would be identical. Sorry, I get it now:)

Comment: I mean, lol, yeah, I could just delete the normalized=true...but it would already be a double redundancy in my code, since I already coded a normalization.  I guess you are right.  It's not like I care about speed at that step.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The regular python `int` function only works for scalars. You should either use a numpy function to round the data, either

```
s = np.round((s - s % bucket_size) / bucket_size) #to round properly; or
s = np.fix((s - s % bucket_size) / bucket_size)   #to round towards 0
```

and if you actually want to convert to an integer type, use

```
s = s.astype(int)
```

to cast your array.

Answer (score 1):

N.B. This answer is less efficient from the point of view that `pandas` is built on top of `numpy`. Please consider `numpy` if going for efficiency.

As for this answer, there is a significant amount of work done using `pandas` data frames, so adding additional conversion to `numpy` means writing extra code. So if one is performing an analysis in say `jupyter notebook`, then we can surely let the programming language do a bit of work under the hood.

*Big thank you to @Chris for noticing this.*

---

## `pandas` version (theoretically less efficient than `numpy`)

#### Create a list with float values:

```
y = [0.1234, 0.6789, 0.5678]
```

#### Convert the list of float values to `pandas` Series

```
s = pd.Series(data=y)
```

#### Round values to three decimal values

```
print(s.round(3))
```

returns

```
0    0.123
1    0.679
2    0.568
dtype: float64
```

#### Convert to integer

```
print(s.astype(int))
```

returns

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
dtype: int64
```

#### Pipe it all

```
pd.Series(data=y).round(3)
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the question. It may be the case that the pandas library is using numpy calls to fulfill this interface.

Comment: @Chris, thank you for the comment, doing a quick web search revealed you are right:
... `pandas` is an open-source library built on top of `numpy` providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language...

There were little requirements about `numpy`, but sure, we could delete it, please let me know when it is time.

Comment: no problem; doesn't matter to me actually. It is a well written answer. Only saying that the accepted answer will stay that way because it answers a more fundamental question.